# Did Firebase Cloud Functions ESLint change recently?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I created a cloud function project with firebase a few months ago, and used linting.

I recently created a new cloud function project with linting, and now the linter is complaining about random rules I never set. I don't remember it enforcing nearly the amount of style rules a few months ago.

Things like:

```
This line has a length of 95. Maximum allowed is 80
Missing JSDoc comment
Missing Trailing comma
expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4
Strings must use singlequote
```

It's also not letting me use async/await.

I found out I can individually set these rules in my .eslintrc.js file, but that's annoying and I don't want to do that. By default, why aren't these rules disabled? I just want basic rules that make sure my code won't fail when run, not random style preferences like single/double quotes and max line length.

Is there any way to use just basic linting functionality with firebase functions?

Comment: They did change with 9.1.1, but you are free to set the [rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) any way you want - be sure to read that documentation.  You will have to decide for yourself what "basic linting functionality" actually means.  But no linter will tell you if your code will definitely not fail.  You have to run it to find that out.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as you. The new, more strict linting rules seem to come from the fact that Firebase functions use the "google" eslint base configuration plugin by default now. Read more about configuring ESLint plugins [in the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-plugins). My older Firebase functions were using tslint without issue.

Here's what my .eslintrc.js file looked like while I was getting style errors from eslint:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        es6: true,
        node: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:import/errors',
        'plugin:import/warnings',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
        'google',
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: ['tsconfig.json', 'tsconfig.dev.json'],
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    ignorePatterns: [
        '/lib/**/*', // Ignore built files.
    ],
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
    rules: {
        quotes: ['error', 'double'],
    },
};
```

I deleted 'google' from the extends property, which seemed to resolve almost all of the style linting issues.

Now it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        es6: true,
        node: true,
    },
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:import/errors',
        'plugin:import/warnings',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: ['tsconfig.json', 'tsconfig.dev.json'],
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    ignorePatterns: [
        '/lib/**/*', // Ignore built files.
    ],
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
    rules: {
        quotes: ['error', 'double'],
    },
};
```

Comment: I also had to get rid of the rules object. I'm very confused as to why (as in why Google is doing it) on one hand you can turn on tslint enforcement which will give linting errors if using double quotes, but then this new default gives errors if using single quotes....

Comment: Removing google worked

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the `google` extends value but I would suggest keeping it and just turning off the rules that bother you the most, which for me is indentation and max length (of lines):

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "indent": ["off"],
    "max-len": ["off"],
  },
};
```

For anyone who is confused by this, there is a lint config file in the Cloud Functions folder that you can edit. As of this answer, that file is named `.eslintrc.js`.

Comment: Why do we even need a rule like max length? In the end don't I just need to test to make sure my function works, regardless of how many characters are in a line?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat semantic rules mostly exist for teams where multiple people are working on the same project; they force consistency to improve code readability, which is important for efficient collaboration. Collaborated source code is often read in web browsers through git repositories and web browsers don't wrap long lines of text by default so enforcing a max length of lines keeps everything in sight so the reader only needs to scroll vertically.

Comment: Ahh ok. So in reality, if I were to disable all of these rules, my code would still run when I deploy my functions, right? I was thinking that these rules were required to be able to execute the code, but if it's purely as a visual help for human readability then that clears this all up for me.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat it’s purely for human readability. There are a lot of sloppy coders out there and nobody likes working with them, even the other sloppy coders.

Comment: Ahhh ok. I might just disable it then since I'm working on a solo project and I'm already highly strict on myself for writing clean code that follows my own patterns. It would be interesting to learn this google syntax, but I guess it's not necessary.